# php error within my database search & show

Tags: php, mysql

So I am having an issue with my DB throwing up all kinds of errors now:

```
<?php
include("includes/db_conx.php");
?>


        <?php

    $query = $_POST['query'];

    $min_length = 1;
  if(strlen($query) >= $min_length)
  {
        $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
        $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($query);
        echo "";


      echo "Image results for <span style='color: #d34639;'>$query</span>" . "<br /><hr />";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM smd_members WHERE mem_username LIKE '$query' ");
        if(!$result){ die(mysqli_error($connection)); }
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo "<a class='usersearch' href='#'><br />".$row['title']."<br /></a><span style='color: #000; font-size: 10pt;'>".$row['title']."<br /></span>";
                }
            }
        else{
            echo "Sorry..No results for $query";
            echo ""; 
        }  
    }
    else{
        echo "Your search keyword contains letters only ".$min_length;
    }
?>
```

The above is my search file which should display the results but I am getting this error:

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/vhosts/jennys-cupcakes.co.uk/marble/search.php on line 16 Image results for
Notice: Undefined variable: connection in /var/www/vhosts/jennys-cupcakes.co.uk/marble/search.php on line 22 Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/vhosts/jennys-cupcakes.co.uk/marble/search.php on line 22 Notice: Undefined variable: connection in /var/www/vhosts/jennys-cupcakes.co.uk/marble/search.php on line 23 Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/vhosts/jennys-cupcakes.co.uk/marble/search.php on line 23

Comment: Did you try `$connection = mysqli_connect('server', 'user', 'password', 'database');` and `$query = mysqli_real_escape_string('your string here', $connection);`?

Comment: @AlejandroIván It isnt the connection failing...it is a very odd one

Answer (score 0):

Check your database connection

ad try this

```
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```